# How to add simulators to JDE

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I have downloaded the BlackBerry JDE 7.0 and also the simulators 9360, 9810 and 9850. Can anyone tell me how can I add these simulators to my JDE?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I dont get what did you download and how.
You can also add what did you try.

Answer (score 2):

Usually after installation of an additional simulator it's possible to select it in a dropdown in the JDE (on the main screen, in the top-right corner).

Comment: thts k I know tht but how to add the downloaded simulators into jde

Comment: @varun: Then you should explain what "to add the downloaded simulators into jde" means for you. What do you expect to get?